# Acumatica Webhooks Fail to make AP or AR invoices

Tags: webhooks, acumatica

I've built out an Acumatica Webhook project. I've successfully got it reading the incoming POST, and figuring out what to what to do. So far I can successfully insert Customers, Customer Locations and Projects without an issue.

Using nearly the same code, I'm trying to insert AP or AR Invoices and I get bizarre or meaningless errors.

I made as simple a function as I could to test inserting just a AR header...

```cs
        public static bool SendHeader()
        {
            using (var scope = GetAdminScope()) // This is how it runs in the webhook, in the admin scope, so thought I could give it a test.
            {
                ARInvoiceEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARInvoiceEntry>();
                ARInvoice theInvoice = new ARInvoice();
                theInvoice.DocType = "INV";
                theInvoice = graph.Document.Insert(theInvoice);
                theInvoice.CustomerID = 7144; // Hard coded to simplify. These are valid values.
                theInvoice.InvoiceNbr = "TEST123";
                graph.Document.Update(theInvoice);
                graph.Save.Press();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

This code will run from a button in any graph (I've tested in VendorMaint and ARInvoiceEntry) but when it run from the inbound webhook I get an error.

```cs
        public PXAction<PX.Objects.AP.VendorR> BtnTEKARHead;
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Send AR Header")]
        protected void btnTEKARHead()
        {
            SendHeader();
        }
```

I stripped down a new webhook to it's BARE minimum, it basically just tries to make a header anytime someone hits it.

```cs
    public class SimpleWebHookHandler : IWebhookHandler
    {
        public async Task<System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult> ProcessRequestAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var scope = GetAdminScope())
            {
                if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
                {
                    string jsonContent = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    SendHeader();
                }
            }
            return new OkResult(request);
        }
   }
```

I hit this endpoint from Postman and I get back  this (mind you, this inserts a header from 2 differant graphs without problem) and it, of course, inserts nothing:

```
 at PX.Data.PXUIFieldAttribute.CommandPreparing(PXCache sender, PXCommandPreparingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnCommandPreparing(String name, Object row, Object value, PXDBOperation operation, Type table, FieldDescription& description)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PrepareParametersForInsert(PXCache sender, Object row, Type[] tables, ISqlDialect dialect, Boolean audit, List`1[] pars)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PersistInserted(PXCache sender, Object row)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()\r\n   at PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoiceEntry.Persist()\r\n   at PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoiceEntryExternalTax.Persist(Action persist)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<HandlerInternal>g__Persist|3_2()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<HandlerInternal>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__38.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__38.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.PressImpl(Boolean internalCall, Boolean externalCall)\r\n   at ServiceTradeWebHooks.Common.SendHeader()\r\n   at TEKServiceTrade.WebHooks.SimpleWebHookHandler.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at PX.Api.Webhooks.Owin.WebhooksController.<Process>d__8.MoveNext()
```

Anyone have thoughts on what it is about the AR/AP graphs that makes this fail? Thanks in advance if you have gotten to the end of this epic....

Comment: This is a simple example that creates 2 webhooks...one that works and one that fails. [link](https://github.com/TravisKleckner/WebhookSimple)